# How do you make a subdomain route for every action in a Zend Framework controller?

Tags: zend-framework, routes

Using Zend Framework I want to use an account name (:account) as the subdomain that will call the basket controller. When using getParams() for the index action it does display the :account parameter but this does not work on any other actions in the basket controller.

This is the code I currently have in the bootstrap:

```
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $domain_name = 'domain.com';
    $plainPathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('');        

    $hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
                    ':account.' . $domain_name,
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'basket'  
                    )
    );
    $router->addRoute('account', $hostnameRoute->chain($plainPathRoute));
```

Thanks in advance for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need two [chained](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.chain) routes:

1. Your subdomain route
2. A route responsible for everything after your domain

I use this config to set up a route this (although I map all subdomains to modules, but i guess you can fix this ;):

```
'subdomain' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname',
    'route' => ':module.localhost',
    'chains' => array(
        'index' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route',
            'route' => ':controller/:action/*'
        )
    )
)
```